# Panel notifcation - how can i update gsettings to add 'skype'

Tags: panel, skype, notification, gsettings

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

shows

`['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']`

How can I make it be

`['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']`

I tried
`gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist ['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']`

but I seem to get an eror and it wasn't changed:-

```
Usage:
  gsettings set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE

Set the value of KEY to VALUE

Arguments:
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']"
```

Have a look at [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings) if you want to use a GUI for this.